# Generating classes from Anonymous types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, anonymous-types

Are there any tools that can generate classes from anonymous types?

I have a complex data structure that I have created using anonymous types. I would like to use this data structure in other places where the anonymous type would be out of scope. That's why I'm looking for such a code generation tool.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's one of the [refactorings](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Convert_Anonymous_to_Named_Type.html) supported by [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).  With nested anonymous types (where one anonymous type has properties of another anonymous type), you'll just have to convert the inner types before you get the option to convert the outer one.

Answer (score 47):

I found another way that will do this without using Resharper. It is tested on VS 2015.

Suppose you have an anonymous type like this:

```
return new
{
    Prop = "val"
};
```

Just give it a name, like this

```
return new AnonType
{
    Prop = "val"
};
```

and after that a light bulb appears near the first line and when you click it, it shows you options that will generate this class for you, wherever you want.

Here you can see what I'm talking about.

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: This is a good solution, but it is noteworthy that, unlike resharper, visual studio will not generate properties if they are implicit. 
e.g. `return new AnonType { foo.Bar };` will not give AnonType a property called Bar, whereas resharper will. To make this work in visual studio, you need to have `return new AnonType { Bar = foo.Bar };`

Comment: down for because of comment above

Comment: @JamesGardner that's not Ahmad's fault or a problem with the answer. That is all VS supports. You may as well make all your declarators explicit first, because once it's a class they can no longer be implicit anyway.

Answer (score 11):

[Resharper - Convert Anonymous to Named Type](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Convert_Anonymous_to_Named_Type.html)

> The Convert Anonymous to Named Type refactoring converts anonymous
>   types to nested or top-level named types in the scope of either the
>   current method (locally) or the whole solution (globally). In the
>   dialog box that this refactoring provides, you can also specify
>   whether ReSharper should generate auto-properties or properties with
>   backing fields, and opt to generate equality and formatting method
>   overrides.
>   [image]

Answer (score 1):

CodeRush supports this with it's [Name Anonymous Type refactoring](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/09/refactorings-for-anonymous-types/#.UchNHPkdtfw).